# How create .p12 file?

Tags: java, digital-signature, e-token

I can not export .p12 file from digital certificate e-token. The option "Yes,export the private key"  is inactive in internet explorer. And "Failed to create the PKCS #12 backup file for unknown reasons." get this message from   firefox. What is the problem??

Comment: The private keys in e-tokens (or other secure elements like smart cards) are not meant to be exportable. This actually is a security feature. So unless the token is flawed, you won't be able to export/backup the private key.

Comment: How do I sign any document with the token using a java application @mkl?

Comment: I assume you would use a PKCS#11 driver for the token.

Comment: Then how can I export the private key?

Comment: You cannot. The signature is created on the token, the private key never is outside it.

Comment: On windows you now also have the option to use the MSCAPI provider - **if** the token is usable within MS CAPI of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mkl

Comment: This related question may help: https://superuser.com/questions/586245/pull-certificate-from-firefox-without-using-firefox